# Forceful Re-render with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import * as React from "react";
// import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
      let [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
      let [height, setHeight] = React.useState(window.innerHeight);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect is called");
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        });
      }, []);
 return (
      <div>
         {/* <button onClick={handler}> Submit </button> */}
         <h1>
         {" "}
            {height},{width}{" "}
          </h1>
      </div>
     );
   }
```

The above code causes **re-render** of **height** and **width** values on the UI `(height =windows.innerHeight & width = windows.innerWidth)` despite using useEffect with an empty dependency array.

I've deployed `useState` inside `useEffect` to update `height` and `width`. My understanding was that `useEffect` gets executed only once(after the initial render) if used with an empty dependency array but on resizing the screen size, `height` and `width` gets updated as well thereby causing **re-render**

Answer (score 1):

1. you should use const to declare your states
2. window.addEventListener is declared only once but it will be triggered every resize - so your state will be updated every resize
3. every time your state change the component will rerender

Comment: _"you should use const to declare your states"_ Why?

Comment: In my opinion it's a good practice

Comment: @Ar26 : So I checked the 2nd point with "click" event - it seems to be behaving similarly to the "resize" event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you added `addEventListener` for resizing window in `useEffect`, So whenever window in resized it's callback function will be called and your states will be changed so your component will be re-rendered

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` is called only once, but since you have added a listener on the window object using `addEventListener`. The code inside the handler (which sets the state) gets executed, whenever there window size is changed. This state update will cause your component to re-render and update the UI

Answer (score 0):

the  `window.addEventListener` method runs just one time and then you have a listener for `resize` and its call back excuted. the `window.addEventListener` does'nt execute on each resize, it's callback does, ist it clear?